# Can I enable Emacs-like keybindings throughout the operating system?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Just looking into elementary OS, and it looks really attractive. I'm a heavy Emacs user; consequently I feel at home on macOS where I can hit `Ctrl-a`, `Ctrl-e`, `Ctrl-k`, etc. to move around, delete lines, etc.

Does elementary OS allow you to set those keystroke system-wide? I'd like to be able to, say, use those when I'm entering text on StackExchange as well as within the address bar of a browser or anywhere I have to enter text.

Comment: Please check gnome-tweak-tool. https://askubuntu.com/questions/245746/emacs-like-keybindings-system-wide

Comment: Is Elementary OS’s DE based off of Gnome then? Where is this mentioned in their docs? @tkskkd

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/18hz8k/emacs_key_bindings_everywhere_in_ubuntu/

Comment: also https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-keyboard/issues/69

Answer (score -1):

is not a good way to integrate this in the system. the system should stay with small and clean footprint. sorry - i think - in present and future there are/will too many Crap in a OS

a keyboard, that can store key-kombinations is for me a perfect deal.
please think about 'ergodox ez' without lightshow.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. I asked if it was possible, and you just said you didn't think it was a good idea and suggested a $350 work-around. That's not a good way to answer a question. Incidentally, I have a QMK keyboard, and I don't think that it would be an adequate substitution for system-wide Emacs bindings, which I think are totally within the scope of any DE, no matter how light. Instead of sharing your opinion, can you tell me definitively whether or not elementary OS supports system-wide Emacs bindings?